# Are there negative performance effects when collecting performance data in IIS?

Tags: iis, performance-monitor, windows-server-2019

I'm using `Windows Server 2019` with `IIS version 10.0.17763.1`, where I count the incoming `GET requests` to my website using the `Performance monitor`. As sample interval I have chosen 15 seconds. Now I want to know whether there are any negative performance effects on my website if I run this monitoring over days, weeks or even months.

Comment: It depends on the power of the server and the number of requests. Of course, make sure there is sufficient space for the log file!

Comment: Ah ok. I have enough space for the log file. Then one should use the performance monitor only for a certain time but then switch it off again. Is that correct?